# How to type complex expression in Wolframalpha

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, wolfram-alpha

I tried to calculate the expression:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{n}{\left(\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+4}}{2}\right)^k+\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+4}}{2}}\right)$$
in Wolframalpha, but it does not interpret it correctly.

Could someone help me type it in and get the answer? Is it $1/2$?

---

**Edit:** This was the [AMM problem 12110](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/AMM12110.pdf), whose deadline passed on 31 August 2019.

As an alternative numerical method, I could calculate the value in MS Excel.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: This question really belongs on *mathematica.stackexchange.com*.

Comment: My CAS (Derive 6) says it converges to $0$. It isn't really made for that type of calculation though

Comment: I would switch to the Wolfram Cloud for this, or you can install the Wolfram Engine for Developers for free: https://www.wolfram.com/engine/

Comment: @AdrianKeister, how to switch to Wolfram Cloud? Wolfram Engine weighs 1Gb, so I will download and try later.

Comment: @bilgamish: Sure! You can sign up for a free account here: https://develop.wolframcloud.com/

Comment: The advantage of the Engine is that you're no longer constrained by server compute time, just your hardware compute time. That is, computations don't "time out" the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite product
$$ f(n) := \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{n}{\left(\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+4}}{2}\right)^k+\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+4}}{2}}\right) \tag1$$
surprisingly can be evaluated in closed form as
$$ f(n) = \frac1{2-n+\sqrt{n^2+4}}. \tag2$$
The limit of $\,f(n)\,$ as
$\,n\to\infty\,$ is $\,1/2.$

If you want to use $\texttt{Mathematica}$ to find the limit, you may
need to give it some help. Another answer suggests that
$\, n = x - 1/x\,$ for some $\,x > 1.\,$ Using this code

```
 Limit[ Product[ 1 - n/(((n + Sqrt[n^2 + 4])/2)^k + (n +
       Sqrt[n^2 + 4])/2) /. (n + Sqrt[n^2 + 4]) -> 2 x /.
       n -> (x^2 - 1)/x, {k, 1, m}], x -> Infinity,
    Assumptions -> m > 1]
```

returns the result `1/2` in under a second. In fact, more is true.
The first factor in the infinite product approaches $\,1/2\,$ as
$\,x \to \infty\,$ while the other factors each approach $\,1.\,$

Answer (score 2):

```
Limit[
     Product[1 - n/(((n + Sqrt[n^2 + 4])/2)^k + (n + Sqrt[n^2 + 4])/2), 
     {k, 1, \[Infinity]}],  
n -> \[Infinity]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the screenshot of MS Excel spreadsheet:

[image]